# Remove blank lines from text which is extracted from pdf file

Tags: python-3.x

I am converting PDF files to text files using pdfminer and then trying to extract contents. But when I do so, there will be some empty lines in text file. I need to remove those empty lines. Can someone tell how can I achieve this.

Text file after conversion:

```
XYZ

8th Semester Undergraduate | Computer Science Engineering | UCE RTU, Kota 

+91 1234567890 | ABCD@gmail.com | 7/108, Malviya Nagar Jaipur (302017) 

SUMMARY 



To seek an opportunity to apply my technology expertise along with my creative problem solving skills in an 
innovative software company. 



EXPERIENCE 





  Machine Learning Engineering Intern , Forsk Technologies , Jaipur  (May,2017 – July,2017)     

Learned the foundational concepts of data science and machine learning including python and statistics, 
enough time was spent on understanding the concept behind each algorithm and examples and case 
studies were done. Built some mid-scaled machine learning models using supervised and unsupervised 
learning. 

  Software Engineering Intern , Proxbotics Creations Technologies , Jaipur (May,2016 – July,2016) 

Developed  and  optimized  various  projects  including  ecommerce,  booking  &  reservation,  non-profit 
organization Websites, using technologies: HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript, MySQL etc.                          

  Trainee at TecheduSoft , Kota  (May,2015) 

The course contains 15+ modules including Android Basics, fragments, screen designing, intents, various 
views, signing app, web servers, web services, notifications, etc.                                                       

PROJECTS 

All projects are available on git: https://github.com/JAIJANYANI 

  Video Analysis for surveillance  

-A command line app which takes all your CCTV feeds as input and filters feeds with abnormal events 
which results in 90% less videos to watch, Used image processing and deep learning algorithms, 
outputs all time-stamps of interesting events for all feeds. 

  Food Calorie Estimator 

-An android app to estimate calories present in food with still image. Trained own Data-set (Meal-net) 
using Transfer learning Built upon Inception V3, Proposed a Deep Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) 
with 48 Layers, Developed a REST API to integrate it in Mobile apps, Optimized total computation time 
~ 2 Seconds. 

  CryptoCurrency Market Predictor 

- A Flask app to predict the future prices of various Crypto Currencies, implemented various supervised 
and deep learning algorithms such as LSTM (RNN), polynomial regression, using scikit-learn, tensorflow, 
keras etc.  

  Spam Filter 

-A REST API to Detect Incoming SMS or Email as Spam or Ham which can be trained on your own data 
set. Used NLP with Naive Bayes for Sentiment Analysis. 


 

Image Classifier using CNN 
-An application which detects objects present in a still image, implemented convolutional neural 
network using open source machine learning library which can be run on multiple machines to reduce 
training workloads, classifies objects using pre-trained image-net model. 

  Online Student and Faculty Portal 

-A Web Portal to manage attendance of students and faculties, can be integrated to mobile apps. Uses 
Php, MySQL, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc. 

  Tax Accounting 

-A Decentralized web app built on Ethereum Block-Chain using Truffle and Embark framework, which 
can be used to transfer funds between accounts which automatically deducts tax from the account. 



TECHNICAL SKILLS 

Programming Languages 

Web Technologies  



Scripting Languages     







Database Management System  



Operating Systems  

Strongest Areas 



COURSES 







: 

: 

: 

: 

: 

C, C++ 

HTML,CSS

Python, PHP, BASH 

MySQL, SQLite 

Microsoft Windows, Linux, UNIX 

             :  

Machine Learning, Data Science 

Applied  Machine  Learning  ,  Applied  Data  Science  ,  Exploratory  Data  Analysis  &  Data  Visualization  ,  Neural 
Networks & Deep Learning , Computer networks , Data Structures & Algorithms , Operating Systems , Cloud 
Computing , Data Mining , Block chain Essentials , Database Management Systems. 



EDUCATION 

  University College of Engineering , Kota : Btech (Pursuing) in Computer Science Engineering  (2018) 
  St. Edmunds School , Jaipur : Senior Secondary (XII) Education Rajasthan  (2012) 
  St. Edmunds School , Jaipur : Secondary (X) Education Rajasthan  (2010)
```

Expected:

```
XYZ 
8th Semester Undergraduate | Computer Science Engineering | UCE RTU, Kota 
+91 1234567890 | ABCD@gmail.com | 7/108, Malviya Nagar Jaipur (302017) 
SUMMARY 
To seek an opportunity to apply my technology expertise along with my creative problem solving skills in an 
innovative software company. 
EXPERIENCE 
-Machine Learning Engineering Intern , Forsk Technologies , Jaipur  (May,2017 – July,2017)     
Learned the foundational concepts of data science and machine learning including python and statistics, 
enough time was spent on understanding the concept behind each algorithm and examples and case 
studies were done. Built some mid-scaled machine learning models using supervised and unsupervised 
learning. 
-Software Engineering Intern , Proxbotics Creations Technologies , Jaipur (May,2016 – July,2016) 
Developed  and  optimized  various  projects  including  ecommerce,  booking  &  reservation,  non-profit 
organization Websites, using technologies: HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript, MySQL etc.                          
-Trainee at TecheduSoft , Kota  (May,2015) 
The course contains 15+ modules including Android Basics, fragments, screen designing, intents, various 
views, signing app, web servers, web services, notifications, etc.                                                       
PROJECTS 
All projects are available on git: https://github.com/JAIJANYANI 
Video Analysis for surveillance  
-A command line app which takes all your CCTV feeds as input and filters feeds with abnormal events 
which results in 90% less videos to watch, Used image processing and deep learning algorithms, 
outputs all time-stamps of interesting events for all feeds. 
-  Food Calorie Estimator 
-An android app to estimate calories present in food with still image. Trained own Data-set (Meal-net) 
using Transfer learning Built upon Inception V3, Proposed a Deep Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) 
with 48 Layers, Developed a REST API to integrate it in Mobile apps, Optimized total computation time 
~ 2 Seconds. 
-  CryptoCurrency Market Predictor 
- A Flask app to predict the future prices of various Crypto Currencies, implemented various supervised 
and deep learning algorithms such as LSTM (RNN), polynomial regression, using scikit-learn, tensorflow, 
keras etc.  
-  Spam Filter 
-A REST API to Detect Incoming SMS or Email as Spam or Ham which can be trained on your own data 
set. Used NLP with Naive Bayes for Sentiment Analysis. 
Image Classifier using CNN 
-An application which detects objects present in a still image, implemented convolutional neural 
network using open source machine learning library which can be run on multiple machines to reduce 
training workloads, classifies objects using pre-trained image-net model. 
Online Student and Faculty Portal 
A Web Portal to manage attendance of students and faculties, can be integrated to mobile apps. Uses 
Php, MySQL, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc. 
Tax Accounting 
-A Decentralized web app built on Ethereum Block-Chain using Truffle and Embark framework, which 
can be used to transfer funds between accounts which automatically deducts tax from the account. 
TECHNICAL SKILLS 
Programming Languages 
Web Technologies  
Scripting Languages     
Database Management System  
Operating Systems  
Strongest Areas 
COURSES 
: 
: 
: 
: 
: 
C, C++ 
HTML, CSS 
Python, PHP, BASH 
MySQL, SQLite 
Microsoft Windows, Linux, UNIX 
             :  
Machine Learning, Data Science 
Applied  Machine  Learning  ,  Applied  Data  Science  ,  Exploratory  Data  Analysis  &  Data  Visualization  ,  Neural 
Networks & Deep Learning , Computer networks , Data Structures & Algorithms , Operating Systems , Cloud 
Computing , Data Mining , Block chain Essentials , Database Management Systems. 
EDUCATION 
University College of Engineering , Kota : Btech (Pursuing) in Computer Science Engineering  (2018) 
St. Edmunds School , Jaipur : Senior Secondary (XII) Education Rajasthan  (2012) 
St. Edmunds School , Jaipur : Secondary (X) Education Rajasthan  (2010)
```

I'm using the below code for the conversion:

```
def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    '''
    Helper function to extract the plain text from .pdf files
    '''
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True,check_extractable=True):
            resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
            fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
            converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, codec='utf-8', laparams=LAParams())
            page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

            text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
            output_txt = text
            yield text
            #print(output_txt)
            converter.close()
            fake_file_handle.close()

def extract_text_from_doc(doc_path):
    '''
    Helper function to extract plain text from .doc or .docx files
    '''
    temp = docx2txt.process(doc_path)
    text = [line.replace('\t', ' ') for line in temp.split('\n') if line]
    return ' '.join(text)

def extract_text(file_path, extension):
    '''
    Wrapper function to detect the file extension and call text extraction function accordingly
    '''
    text = ''
    if extension == '.pdf':
        for page in extract_text_from_pdf(file_path):
            text += ' ' + page
    elif extension == '.docx' or extension == '.doc':
        text = extract_text_from_doc(file_path)
    print(text)

    return text
```

Comment: If return ``str()`` you can try ``somestring.replace(" ", "")``

Comment: If I'm reading this right, `output_txt = text.strip()`. Then `yield output_txt`. Or if you're reading in each line of the document in the second function, replace `temp.split('\n')`  with `temp.strip()`, which removes blank lines and extra white space in line strings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use regex.

```
import re
rc = re.compile(r"\n{2,}")  # two and more new lines
string_without_extra_new_lines = re.sub(rc,"\n", string_with_extra_blank_lines)
```

Having this as an example:

```
XYZ

8th Semester Undergraduate | Computer Science Engineering | UCE RTU, Kota 

+91 1234567890 | ABCD@gmail.com | 7/108, Malviya Nagar Jaipur (302017) 

SUMMARY 



To seek an opportunity to apply my technology expertise along with my creative problem solving skills in an 
innovative software company. 



EXPERIENCE
```

This is the output:

```
XYZ
8th Semester Undergraduate | Computer Science Engineering | UCE RTU, Kota
+91 1234567890 | ABCD@gmail.com | 7/108, Malviya Nagar Jaipur (302017)
SUMMARY
To seek an opportunity to apply my technology expertise along with my creative problem solving skills in an
innovative software company.
EXPERIENCE
```